# how to subctract in type script big numbers?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, typescript, test

I'm trying to to subctract in type script big numbers, but getting error...

```
const supply1 = 100000;
 const _amount = 100;
 const supply = ethers.utils.parseEther(`${supply1}`);
 const diff = supply - _amount;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ethers.utils.parseEther`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/) function returns a [BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/).

To make arithmetic operations on it you must explicitely call the operation implementation, in your case that would be the [`.sub`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/bignumber/src.ts/bignumber.ts#L79) method which expects a [BigNumberish](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumberish) parameter.

So you'd want to change :

```
const diff = supply - _amount;
```

to :

```
const diff = supply.sub(_amount);
```

Just keep in mind that `diff` will be of type BigNumber, if you need to convert it to another type such as number or string, you can refer to the appropriate part of [the documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--BigNumber--methods--conversion).